# how to confirm my dll has been loaded successfully in Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I put my dll file in myJre/bin ,and used System.loadLibrary();

```
static {
        try {
            //System.loadLibrary("IFaaS4ENetSDK");
            System.loadLibrary("IFassSDK");
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

when I start to debug ,the codes show me that the dll has been loaded successfully 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/346HD.png)

but when call method in dll 。it's failed..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hzJN.png)

Comment: Remove images and copy paste your code/errors.

Comment: Make sure you have the method inside you dll.

Comment: Take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001 - you can find there a simple explanation of how your call from Java is mapped to symbol inside library.

Comment: images sometimes are very hard to read, even blocked in some networks. (copy&paste from text is also much easier than from images).... if you want to post messages, code, ... please post the text (**additionally** including the image **can** be helpful) - I can only think of one solution for your problem, include a function that just returns some value (version?) to confirm the DLL is loaded, not that different as you probably are already doing [:-|

Comment: it could also be helpful to see the method declaration (Java) and function implementation (DLL)